# ESlint says a variable is unused but I think it is being used

Tags: eslint

I have an eslint.yml file like so:

```
env:
  browser: true
  node: false
parser: "babel-eslint"
parserOptions:
  allowImportExportEverywhere: true
  ecmaVersion: 2018
  sourceType: "module"


rules:
  max-len:
    - error
    - 120
    -
      ignoreComments: true
      ignoreTrailingComments: true
      ignoreTemplateLiterals: true

globals:
  Pikaday: false
```

The following code has an error saying that the variable "clinician" is not used.

```
      let clinician = day[staffer.occ][staffer.index];
      if ((staffer.occ === 'optom' && this.optom[staffer.index].ersatz && availability.rescheduled > 0) ||
        availability.attended > 0) {
        error = 'error';
      } else if (availability.rescheduled > 0) {
        error = 'warning';
      }
      if (availability.unavailablereason.trim().length > 0 ) {
        clinician = {...clinician, error: error, klass: this.lookup.unavail[availability.unavailablereason.trim()],
          reason: availability.unavailablereason };
      } else {
        clinician = {...clinician, error: error};
      }
```

but its being used with the `spread` operator.

Am I misunderstanding something or is my eslint.yml file configured incorrectly? or what?

Answer (score 1):

You only use `clinician` to assign a new value to `clinician` again. So if you don't use `clinician` further down the code for something else, it's not really needed.

Comment: I don't understand how not needed.  This code changes the object reference to `day[staffer.occ][staffer.index]` so elsewhere in the code something which checks to see if the value is different will see the object has changed and can work on the changed subfields. Am I supposed to use the `day[staffer.occ][staffer.index]` everywhere were I currently use `clinician`

Comment: Ok, I see. But I think ESLint is not able to recognize that you are using the object of which clinician is a reference to. So it still considers the variable unused. It's not about the spread operator. When you use Object.assign or sth similar instead of spread, it would be the same ESLint error I think.